# Expo 49.0.11: web doesn't compile

Tags: reactjs, expo, webpack-dev-server

I have this problem: I have created a new expo-project with a clear installation but I'm still fighting with this problem (I haven't done any changes):

```
(node:1331) [DEP_WEBPACK_DEV_SERVER_CONSTRUCTOR] DeprecationWarning: Using 'compiler' as the first argument is deprecated. Please use 'options' as the first argument and 'compiler' as the second argument.(Use `node --trace-deprecation ...` to show where the warning was created)(node:1331) [DEP_WEBPACK_DEV_SERVER_LISTEN] DeprecationWarning: 'listen' is deprecated. Please use the async 'start' or 'startCallback' method.
```

How can I fix this error? I think there are problems with the new sdk version of Expo (49).

What do you think about that? Thank yoy

[package.json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Iu7lw.png)
[app.json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iOyHY.png)

Comment: Did you solve this issue?

Comment: Yes, I have watched this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1CVlTqHW5xQ